# Stripe CLI on DEBIAN server, how do I make it "listen" to new requests in the background and continue using the console?

Tags: console, stripe-payments, debian, command-line-interface, background-process

I want to use Stripe CLI and WEBHOOKS events on my debian(10.1) server. I've managed to get everything working but my problem is that when I run:

`stripe listen --forward-to localhost:8000/foo/webhooks/stripe/`

that I can't use the console anymore, because its listening to incoming events, which I still need. The only shown option is ^C to quit, but I need the CLI listener to continue to run at all times while being able to do other stuff at the same time.

On my local version/editor I can add sessions and run the listen command from one terminal and use another terminal session to continue interact with the system. But I dont know how to do that with debian yet. It would be great if the listen function could just run in the background and I could continue with what I need to do without stopping to listen. My next idea was to tunnel via ssh to the server but im unsure if that would solve my problem. Wouldnt that mean that my computer at home running that session would need to be running at all time? Im lost here...

Btw the server is a droplet on Digital Ocean if that matters...which I dont think.

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: You should be able to SSH to your server in multiple terminal windows on your machine so that you can run `stripe listen` on one and other commands on the other. https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/droplets/how-to/connect-with-ssh/ is likely a good start, or talking to DigitalOcean's support team to guide you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE/SOLVED:

I missunderstood my problem, the Stripe CLI is just for testing local. Once a stripe solution is in production, Stripes servers send requests to my server/endpoints.

If you are wondering about this or want to read more start here how it works in production: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/go-live